# aiohttp.web + aiopg + sqlalchemy: random "cursor.execute() called while another coroutine is already waiting for incoming data" under load

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I have a trivial `aiohttp.web` application that executes SQL requests via `aiopg` sqlalchemy integration. It's as simple as:

```
import aiohttp.web
from aiopg.sa import create_engine

app = aiohttp.web.Application()


async def rows(request):
    async with request.app["db"].acquire() as db:
        return aiohttp.web.json_response(list(await db.execute("SELECT * FROM table")))

app.router.add_route("GET", "/rows", rows)


async def init(app):
    app["db"] = await create_engine(host="postgres", user="visio", password="visio", database="visio")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    handler = app.make_handler()

    loop.run_until_complete(init(app))

    loop.run_until_complete(loop.create_server(handler, "0.0.0.0", 80))
    loop.run_forever()
```

When server load reaches 100 rps, this error starts appearing randomly:

```
RuntimeError: cursor.execute() called while another coroutine is already waiting for incoming data
  File "aiohttp/server.py", line 261, in start
    yield from self.handle_request(message, payload)
  File "aiohttp/web.py", line 88, in handle_request
    resp = yield from handler(request)
  File "visio_longer/views/communicate/__init__.py", line 72, in legacy_communicate
    device = await query_device(db, access_token)
  File "visio_longer/views/communicate/__init__.py", line 31, in query_device
    (Device.access_token == access_token)
  File "aiopg/utils.py", line 72, in __await__
    resp = yield from self._coro
  File "aiopg/sa/connection.py", line 103, in _execute
    yield from cursor.execute(str(compiled), post_processed_params[0])
  File "aiopg/cursor.py", line 103, in execute
    waiter = self._conn._create_waiter('cursor.execute')
  File "aiopg/connection.py", line 186, in _create_waiter
    'already waiting for incoming data' % func_name)
```

It happens with random queries at random times, once in a few days, sometimes these errors come in bunch of 4 or 2. Is there something wrong with my code? `aiohttp` and `aiopg` versions are latest from pip

Answer (score 0):

It think you forgot to acquire a cursor

```
 async with conn.cursor() as cur:
     await cur.execute("SELECT 1")
```

Comment: It's an aiopg sqlalchemy integration (note `from aiopg.sa import create_engine`). It acquires cursor internally.